# How can I read the value from complex adaptive card?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, adaptive-cards

I am able to read the values if the body have only input text. This case have columnset and column. When I filled all the input data and click on submit button from emulator I am not getting any value.

Platform : .Net C#

Below I have shared the json card details. Could you please help me to fix this issue.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "0.5",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "size": 2,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Tell us about yourself...",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "size": "large"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "We just need a few more details to get you booked for the trip of a lifetime!",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Don't worry, we'll never share or sell your information.",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "wrap": true,
              "size": "small"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Your name",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "myName",
              "placeholder": "Last, First"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Your email",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "myEmail",
              "placeholder": "youremail@example.com",
              "style": "email"
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Phone Number"
            },
            {
              "type": "Input.Text",
              "id": "myTel",
              "placeholder": "xxx.xxx.xxxx",
              "style": "tel"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "size": 1,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "Image",
              "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Diver_Silhouette%2C_Great_Barrier_Reef.jpg",
              "size": "auto"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Submit"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but the last time I tried with the adaptive card, the *submit action doesn't work well with column set*, maybe you can remove all the columns and test if it works out for you

Comment: if I remove the column set it will work but I have not tested. I would like to get result from column set

Comment: then maybe you can try the Action.Http instead of Action.Submit, and use the body like "key=value&key2=value2"

Comment: This was a bug we fixed in the HTML renderer a few weeks back, but doesn't seem to be in your version of the WebChat control/emulator. I'll look into how we can get the build updated

Comment: You are saying the message.Value is empty?

Comment: +1 @MattHidinger, same problem here and also not working on the webchat embedded on the dev framework portal

Comment: @EzequielJadib yes

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question just for clarity if someone see this,

the underlying issue was fixed quite some time ago and if you're working with AdaptiveCards like that you get all the values just fine wether those are in columnsets or not.